# Avoid last item overflowing content

Tags: html, css

I'm building a tooltip system and I'm getting problems with the last tooltip from the list. I tried using `.toprightcontrols .btnClass:last-of-type .tooltip-text { right: 0; }` but nothing happens. I tried also using `:last-child` instead of `:last-of-type` too but no success...

```js
let collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text]");
collection.forEach((ele, ind) => {
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.className = "tooltip-text";
element.innerText = ele.dataset.text;
element.dataset.name = "_" + ele.id + ind;
document.getElementById(ele.id).appendChild(element);
         
    document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'visible';
     }, false);

   document.querySelector('#' + ele.id).addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        document.querySelector('[data-name="' + element.dataset.name + '"]').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }, false);

});
```

```css
.btnClass {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-text {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 95vh;
}

.c-content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toprightcontrols {
  margin: 0 1.2% 0 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.btnClass {
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: right;
}

.btnClass:before {
  content: url('https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/nLMdieVITRSq82yZdqlWOw.png');
}

p.tooltip-text {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 6px 8px 20.2px 8px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  animation: fadein 0.2s ease-in;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  right: 0;
}

p.tooltip-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="c-content">
                <div class="toprightcontrols">
                    <span name="btn1" id="btn1" class="btnClass" data-text="Hello there"></span>
                    <span name="xxxxx" id="xxxxx" class="btnClass" data-text="Tooltip"></span>
                    <span name="something" id="something" class="btnClass" data-text="Click me"></span>
                    <span name="randomid" id="randomid" class="btnClass" data-text="I'm a text"></span>
               </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The expected result must be something like this =>
[image]

How do I fix this? I don't know if I'm following the right way trying to catch the last element... probably I can fix this using Javascript detecting the last element but I prefer using pure CSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific question you can try:

```css
.btnClass:last-of-type .tooltip-text {
  left: auto;
  transform: none;
  right: 10px;
}

.btnClass:last-of-type .tooltip-text::before {
  left: calc(100% - 12px);
}
```

---

It's not a particularly sturdy solution, though. For example, if the tooltip text in the next-to-last "button" is too long you will encounter the same issue, it will "leak out" on the right.

You could use `<button type="button">` instead of `span` if it's something interactive for the user.

You could use a pseudoelement (`::after`) on the button with `content: attr(data-text)` instead of the `p` for a simpler HTML…

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have a question: wouldn't it be bad practice to use button without href?

Comment: You're probably thinking of `<a>`, and yes, anchors should be used only when you're actually going to a different link or jumping to some content within a page. `<button>` element is commonly used within `<form>` but it can also be used as standalone interactive element, you add the `type="button"` in that case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/buttonhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button